# In APA, how do I cite two sources in a sentence? Where one mentions another and I want to retain the reference of that mention

Tags: apa

For instance, the author that is commentating on the primary source is named Foster.

The primary source is Dante's Inferno. I want to make reference to the primary source that Foster is addressing in the in-text citation but I also want to reference Foster.

In APA format, should the sentence look like this:

Foster (1964) notes that Dante makes use of x, y and z (p. 101, Inf. XVI, 23).

p. 101 is for Foster, while Inf. XVI, 23 is for Dante.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not clear: it looks like “p. 101” refers to Dante’s Inferno.  Instead, I would put the page number for Foster with the year for that source, not at the end, if you even include it at all (not being a direct quote, it is not required). In APA, you [don’t need to put the page number at the end](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/03/how-to-cite-direct-quotations.html) of the sentence:

> “A flexible mind is a healthy mind,” according to Palladino and Wade’s (2010, p. 147) longitudinal study.

Because you mention the sources separately by name, you should have completely separate parentheticals. Compare the examples for [multiple in-text citations](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/01/writing-in-text-citations-in-apa-style.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you cite Foster verbatim, you give his citations as they appear in his text:

> "Dante (Inf. XVI, 23) makes use of x, y, and z." (Foster, 1964, p. 101)

If you refer to Foster indirectly, paraphrase the citation:

> Foster (1964, p. 101) notes that Dante makes use of x, y, and z in canto XVI, verse 23, of *Inferno*.

Since you will probably use Foster's argument in a context where you are already talking about *Inferno* or that passage in particular, you may skip part of the reference to Dante's work:

> While Dante has avoided [whatever x, y, and z are] throughout most of canto XVI, Foster (1964, p. 101) noted that he makes use of x, y, and z when Vergil encounters Rusticucci, Guerra, and Aldobrandi at the waterfall.